# Adding new Rows while choosing a Column # depending on the loop #

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have rows in SQL exactly like the following (row 1 and 2):

[image]

The important thing that i want is to add each row 12 times again to this same table.
The columns 1 to 12 contain monthly budget information per category (each row).
I would need this in the format of 12 rows where the budget is in the field DT_VALUE_Nbr, as the software reading this needs one budget number/row.

It's no problem that the 12 lines are added to the same table for now, i will change this in the future, i just don't know how to write loops in vba in which you change a record set and insert the modified recordset into the db.

I was recommended to do this as an Access VBA Module because many calculations already happen with modules.

My Query for the table:

```
SQL = " SELECT AS_VAR_ORG_Version_SK, ORG_Sk, VAR_Sk, DT_VALUE_Nbr, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] " & _
      " FROM dbo.AAAAAA_TEMP "
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  ARe you trying to write `line 1` 12 times with each `DT_VALUE_Nbr` being a different month?  So line one should be `15156`, line two should be `51563153`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this data in **Excel** on `"Sheet1"`:

[image]

You can run this code:

```vb
Sub testit()

Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, NewRow As Long, DestLast As Long
Dim DataSht As Worksheet, DestSht As Worksheet

Set DataSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set DestSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
LastRow = DataSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

DestSht.Cells.Clear

DataSht.Rows(1).Copy
DestSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
DestSht.Range("F1").Value = "Month"
DestSht.Range("G1:Q1").Delete

For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
    For NewRow = 1 To 12
        DestLast = DestSht.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        DataSht.Range("A" & CurRow & ":Q" & CurRow).Copy
        DestSht.Range("A" & DestLast).PasteSpecial
        DestSht.Range("E" & DestLast).Value = DestSht.Cells(DestLast, NewRow + 5).Value
        DestSht.Range("F" & DestLast).Value = NewRow
        DestSht.Range("G" & DestLast & ":Q" & DestLast).Delete
    Next NewRow
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

And get this output on `"Sheet2"`:

[image]

Comment: For some reason that code 1:1 didn't work for me (look at first column of output), it was perfect. I now use

`For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
Year = 201401
    For NewRow = 1 To 12
        DestLast = DestSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        DataSht.Range("A" & CurRow & ":Q" & CurRow).Copy
        DestSht.Range("A" & DestLast).PasteSpecial
        DestSht.Range("D" & DestLast).Value = DestSht.Cells(DestLast, NewRow + 5).Value
     DestSht.Range("E" & DestLast).Value = Year
     Year = Year + 1
     DestSht.Range("F" & DestLast & ":Q" & DestLast).Delete
    Next NewRow
Next CurRow`